# Why is Joda LocalTime being render as String in Json Grails?

Tags: json, grails, groovy, render, localtime

I am using LocalTime duration for a WorkDone domain class field in grails. When using render as JSON this field is rendered as a String not as a Object. I thought that this was because of toString() method in this class.

```
class WorkDone{
   LocalTime duration
}

Json output = {"duration":"00:00:00"}
```

But if I implement this field with my custom class CustomDuration its displaying the whole object in generated JSON string.
I have also implemented toString() method in this class.

```
class WorkDone{
    CustomDuration duration
}

json output = {"duration":{ durFieldInDurationClass:"00:00:00"}}
```

Why am I seeing this behaviour?

I have this map in both cases:

```
grails.converters.JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(WorkDone ) {
def returnMap = [:]
returnMap.put("duration", it.duration)
return returnMap
}
```

My custom duration class

```
 class CustomDuration{
     String durFieldInDurationClass
     String toString(){
       return durFieldInDurationClass
     }
    }
```

I am using `render workdoneobject as JSON` in controller to generate this output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class CustomDuration{
 String durFieldInDurationClass
 String toString(){
   return durFieldInDurationClass
 }
 static {
  grails.converters.JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(CustomDuration) {
     return it.duration
    }
}
```